# how to implement airplay on Mac using AVPlayer

Tags: macos, avplayer, osx-mavericks

I made app using MediaPlayer framework on iOS and I can enable AirPlay:

on iOS:

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];

playercontroller.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
```

But on Mac MediaPlayer framework is not available. I'm using AVPlayer framework to play video but I can not figure out how to enable airplay using AVPlayer. Any of you knows how to enable airplay using AVPlayer?

Comment: Put four spaces before each line of code to format it properly.